# OPENSTACK - Risk-Based authentication in keystone

Tags: authentication, cloud, openstack, keystone

I need recommendations on including risk-based authentication in the Keystone API. How i can proceed?

Now, I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Hey, stack, welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Please be specific about the technical problem you're facing, so people can provide precise answers.

Comment: thanks for reply, i want the mechanism to integrate risk-based authentication in keystone for authenticate people with their context (localization, device..), i want just the idea for start

Comment: The place to start is https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/pike/advanced-topics/external-auth.html